# Photogallery without Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently trying to implement a photo gallery in my homepage without using JS.

I have the following code online but I do not understand what the line in the middle is precisely doing.

```
.image-gallery .big-image a:target img {display:block;}
.image-gallery .big-image a:target ~ img#default {display:none; width:1px;}
.image-gallery .big-image img#default {display:block;}
```

The tilde is supposed to connect the parent (a:target) and the #default image.
I know what target is supposed to do, but what is the `target` after the `a` supposed to do?
And why do I need it?

Comment: Please post your markup as well. a:target ~ img#default means those two elements are siblings that are not neseccarily next to each other, but on the same level.

Comment: The tilde (i.e. `~`) selector selects an element with a certain element preceding it. In your case, though, I'm uncertain of why you would have in on an element with an  id.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to provide specific answer as you didn't provide markup. However, the following articles should provide the necessary information to figure the ~ and :target selectors.

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/t/target/

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/g/general-sibling/

My best educated guess from what was provided is that :target is being used to deep link directly to an image in the gallery. For example, if a user were to go to image 3 in the gallery, the URL may change to /gallery#3. If they shared that URL, the gallery would automatically go to the third image in the gallery. The "~ img#default" is likely to hide the default starting image if a user deep links to an image. Again, this is just a guess as no markup is provided.